# Linked List in C : Having issues with entering string and displaying it

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have written a code for Linked List:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student{
       char name[256];
       int id;  
       struct student *next;
};
  struct student *start;
  struct student *last;     

void enter(void);
void add( struct student *i,struct student **last);
void display(struct student *first);       

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  start=last=NULL;

   enter();
   enter();
   enter();
   display(start);

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}

void add( struct student *i,struct student **last)
{
     if (!*last){ *last=i; start=i;}
     else {(*last)->next=i;*last=i;}
     i->next=NULL;

     }
void enter(void)
{
   struct student *info;

   info=(struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));



    printf("Enter the name of the student:\n");
    fgets(info->name,255,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    // gets(info->name);
     printf("Enter the student id:\n");
     scanf("%d%",&info->id); 
     add(info,&last);

 }

 void display(struct student *first)
 {
      while(first)
      {
                  printf("\n\n\n\nName: %s\n",first->name);
                  printf("Id: %d\n", first->id);
                  first=first->next;
                  }
  }
```

It does create a linked list but when i try to input the values: it shows

[image: OUTPUT]

For first element it takes the name correctly for id i need to manually enter \n after the id digit (otherwise it does not come out of the scanf mode) and 2nd element onwards it does not prompt to take the name and it skips "Enter name" and asks for id where again I need to manually enter \n. While showing the linked list elements , it does show first name but 2nd name onwards shows \n. I have already used fflush(stdin). Could you please let me know why such behavior? I have attached the o/p pic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had a nickel...

Anyway, there are a number of problems here:

1) Don't `fflush(stdin)`, that's undefined behavior

2) It's never a good idea to mix `scanf`s and `fgets`s, it just makes things confusing.

```
scanf(" %s", info->name); // will do instead of your fgets statement
```

3) You have an extra `%` in your scanf:

```
scanf("%d%",&info->id);  // should be scanf("%d",&info->id);
```

---

For completeness...

Why you're having problems right now:

`fgets()` takes a string and includes the newline, so when you're asking for a name you're getting "name\n"

`scanf()` takes the number and ***leaves*** the newline. So when you ask for an ID, you'll get the digit typed, but the newline character `'\n'` is still sitting in `stdin`.

Next time that your `fgets()` runs it will automatically take that as the input for the second name. Seeming to "skip over" the request for input.

---

**EDIT**

If the reason you were using `fgets()` was to read a string with spaces in it (like `"first_name last_name"`) that can be acomplished with `scanf()` as well using the Negated scanset option:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",info->name);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike , "3) You have an extra % in your scanf:" - it resolved \n issue, but string one still there. scanf("%s",info->name); does not take space between first and last name and the last name including the white space goes to next element of list. fflush(stdin) with or without - same o/p with issue that was before with strings.

Comment: Ok.. thanks Mike.... I got the idea watz the issue reading your edited remarks... cheers

Comment: @GauravK - Well you didn't mention you wanted to take a space in your input :P   See my edit on how to take a space in `scanf()`

Comment: But I want to accept spaces between first, middle and last name. scanf() can not do this. How do i proceed then ?

Comment: @Mike.. scanf("%[^\n]",info->name); escaped name entry for 2nd and 3rd elements and produced weird name output for 2nd and 3rd elements.. :P

Comment: @GauravK - I missed a space when I was typing. `scanf(" %[^\n]",info->name);` You have a leftover `'\n'` from entering the digit so you need that one space before the `%` in the scanf to tell it to disregard any previous white space.

Comment: @netcoder - but I don't see any reason why `scanf(" %s", ...)` isn't.

Comment: @Mike: Because a user can easily overflow your buffer. `scanf`-family functions with strings should always be used with a width specifier to prevent that, e.g.: `char foo[50]; scanf("%49s", foo);`.

Comment: @netcoder So watz d efficient solution to my issue? scanf(" %[^\n]",info->name); does give me expected result..

Comment: @Mike : Can u tell me adding space b4 scanf("%[^\n]",info->name); , how does it make scanf read the space.  I read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/  but could not figure it out.

Comment: @Netcoder: I used scanf(" %[^\n]256s",info->name); and it is giving expected result, and  I guess it will not overflow my buffer.

Comment: @GauravK - At the link you pointed to, look under Parameters, under format, to the first bullet (Whitespace characters). There it says `function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters`. So by adding that space, it's saying "ignore any left over newlines".  **Side note** if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted (click the check mark next to it) to let others know your Question is fixed.